# Green's Functions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, harmonic-oscillator, greens-functions

I am having trouble understanding how to apply Green's function to an impulsive forcing function.

I am having trouble understanding how to use Green's function to solve for the motion of a driven damped harmonic oscillator.

I'll sum up what I know and hopefully someone can fill the gaps in my understanding.

So the problems is  $\frac{F(t)}{m} = 0$ for  $t < 0$,   $A\frac{t^2}{\tau^2}$ for $0  < t < \tau$,   and $A$ for $t > \tau$

I need to solve for the motion so that is find $x(t)$. $$x(t) = \int F(t')G(t,t')dt'$$ I take $F(t`)$ from the problem I'm given but I have 3 different force functions so do I end up with 3 different $x(t)$ functions? and the text book says $$G(t,t') = \frac{1}{m\omega_1}\exp(-\beta(t-t'))\sin(\omega_1(t-t'))$$ so do I plug that in 3 different times? I'm really lost in terms of how to apply use Green's functions to solve this problem. Am I right to think that there is only one Green function or is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can see no problem with that, you'll just have a piecewise as a result of integrating the Green's function and de external force F(t') between the corresponding time interval. However, you must take into account that x(t) must be continuous.

Comment: Thank you! I had to use an integral calculator and it was a big mess but I got it figured out. My TA said if I just summed all the integrated components into one equation that takes care of the need for continuity. I need to read more to understand the theory of why Green's functions work but at least I can answer the questions now! Thanks again.